# redis-py AttributeError: 'PubSub' object has no attribute 'get_message'

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I write the code in Windows Command Line.
The code is just from Redis-py's [GitHub page](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#publish--subscribe).
[image]

I don't know how this happens,so I.

```
dir(p)
```

The result is:
[image]

I cannot find "get_message".
My redis is version -2.9.1.

Comment: What version is in `redis.__version__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_message` is not part of `2.9.1` release. It will be part of future [2.10.0 release](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/CHANGES)

For `2.9.1` you should use `.listen()` method.